# SSH tunneling blocked on 20.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, firewall

I tried using Hamachi to play with a friend and he told me there was a vpn error next to my name. We could not connect at all and I tried everything to fix it. According to this website https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-hamachi-vpn-status-error/ the error could either be due to a VPN or my firewall blocking SSH tunneling...

- I'm on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, only a week into use.
- I have never downloaded a VPN, other than Hamachi itself.
- I haven't messed with my firewall or anything to do with my internet. I use ethernet through powerline.
- I use a GigaByte H310M motherboard (in case the problem could be in my BIOS)
- *I have yet to test Hamachi on my laptop to determine if the problem is my router*.

Does Ubuntu block this by default? Is there a way for me to check what could be blocking it if not the firewall itself? How do I fix it?

---

Things have gotten weirder. I will clarify one thing: I have only tried using Hamachi with *a single friend* so far and the VPN error shows up for him. With that said...

I booted an entirely different computer, running windows 10, downloaded Hamachi fresh out of the website and loaded into the server we had made. The same error showed up there, exactly the same as it was before and I know that it isn't the Windows Firewall blocking it.

I did some of the steps from the link that @WinEunuuchs2Unix provided to set up UFW on Linux and allow shh, http and https. Still the error showed up for my friend. After that I went on to my routers configuration website and manually put in ssh port forwarding as well as changing a few other things. The SAME error. I undid most of the stuff on my router just in case for safety.

At this point the problem is either: my router's manufacturers made it somehow impossible to use ssh. *OR* my friend is the problem. In either case this is no longer a Linux problem, so if there is any other possibility here, comment and we'll keep the rabbit hole going.

Comment: Not sure about the software you are using but you could try googling their names and "open ports" at the same time for solutions.

Comment: @user68186 UFW is inactive. It was already on my OS.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I was trying to play Minecraft Java with Hamachi, I used only Hamachi and Haguichi. I am certain that the Java and Minecraft installations are not an issue here. I will check my router soon and be sure to fill y'all in. Until then, could it be a problem in my BIOS? Where would I look?

Comment: I had never heard of Hamachi until today. I have no idea how it works. So I can't tell you where to look. I doubt the problem is in the BIOS. But then one can't be sure.

Comment: @kaiserkothe The open ports aren't set in router or BIOS so much as your firewall: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-open-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-linux-12-04-14-04-lts/

Comment: Hi and welcome. You need to remove all these comments and answers, All that information belongs in the question. No one is going to weed through all this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now: my UFW looks like this.

To--------------------                          Action------      From

22/tcp---------------                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp---------------                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp-------------                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25565/tcp----------                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25565/udp---------                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
12975/tcp----------                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
32976/tcp----------                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)---------                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)---------                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)-------               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25565/tcp (v6)----             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25565/udp (v6)---             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
12975/tcp (v6)----             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
32976/tcp (v6)----             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Outgoing is set to allow by default. Ports 12975 and 32976 were provided by Hamachi https://support.logmeininc.com/central/help/which-ports-and-protocols-does-logmein-hamachi-use but even so, I don't even think I really needed to add them to the UFW, but I did just in case.

I also went on my router's configuration website and port-forwarded port 22 to my computer, just in case.

I made a brand new server and got a different friend to join. *He said I didn't have any vpn error, even sent me a photo because I couldn't believe it*. I have no idea exactly what I did wrong or right in this but as long as it is working I won't change it.